# Coprime integer solutions to $ \frac{x^n \pm y^n}{x \pm y}=z^m $ with $n>5 , m>1$

Tags: diophantine-equations, nt.number-theory

Are there coprime integer solutions to:
$$ \frac{x^n \pm y^n}{x \pm y}=z^m $$
with $n>5 , m>1$ and excluding $z=0$?

I suppose the abc conjecture implies finitely many solutions.

Comment: I suppose you also want to rule out $x=y=z=1$. 

Answer (score 5):

I suspect this question is very difficult to answer without additional hypotheses.
The case $y=1$ is the classic Nagell-Ljunggren equation, where, unlike the (on the
surface) very similar equation of Catalan, we do not even know whether there exist
finitely many solutions in the variables $(x,z,n,m)$. If we fix $m=2$ and $n > 5$ prime,
say, then it is still a substantial problem to solve the corresponding equation;
Ivorra [Dissertationes Math. 444 (2007)] treats the cases $n \in \{ 7, 11, 13, 17 \}$
via elliptic Chabauty.

Comment: @Mike Thank you. Is the case $n=5, m=2$ clear? It appears to be a quartic model of elliptic curve for fixed y.

Comment: This curve has positive rank and (I think) conductor $200$, if memory serves, so there are infinitely many solutions to the corresponding equation....

Comment: For $n=5,m=2$, $\langle x,y,z \rangle =\langle 3k, k, 11k^2\rangle$ is a family of solutions (with both $\pm$ being $-$), but I suppose we are to assume that $\gcd(x,y)=1$.